# Polymer 1.0 - chart elements

Tags: charts, pie-chart, polymer-1.0

I want to add a pie chart element in my project. I saw there are a few chart elements available at [here](http://robdodson.github.io/chart-elements/components/chart-elements/).

Where I can download them from? Is there a bower install option? Also I am not sure if the above charts are compatible with 1.0.

Please help me either with bower install syntax or a resource where I can download from. I tried with `bower install chart-pie` but it said `bower ENOTFOUND     Package chart-pie not found`

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: I finally got bower install syntax. It is `bower install chart-elements`**

Answer (score 0):

I cant' see anything about installing via `bower` in the docs or in the README file of the [github repo](https://github.com/robdodson/chart-elements). You'll probably have to download it from github and then copy the `chart-pie.html` file into your project. Note that the `bower.json` file for this project has a dependency on `chartjs`. You'll need to make sure you have that downloaded via `bower` too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Seems like https://github.com/robdodson/chart-elements is the one I was looking for! Will download and try to implement

Comment: I finally got bower install syntax. It is bower install chart-elements